# Метод удаления объекта из БД при нажатии на кнопку. Spring Boot + Hibernate + Thymeleaf

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Всем привет! Нашел в сети интересный проект "Онлайн-магазин" на Spring Boot. Но возникла проблема когда я попытался добавить кнопку Удалить продукт из списка.
Объясните пожалуйста что не так. Вот мой класс Admin Controller:

```
    package com.webapp.agroxapp.controller;

          import java.util.List;

         import org.apache.commons.lang.exception.ExceptionUtils;
           import com.webapp.agroxapp.dao.OrderDAO;
   import com.webapp.agroxapp.dao.ProductDAO;
       import com.webapp.agroxapp.entity.Product;
      import com.webapp.agroxapp.form.ProductForm;
       import com.webapp.agroxapp.model.OrderDetailInfo;
       import com.webapp.agroxapp.model.OrderInfo;
       import com.webapp.agroxapp.pagination.PaginationResult;
         import com.webapp.agroxapp.validator.ProductFormValidator;
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
         import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
        import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
       import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
        import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
         import org.springframework.ui.Model;
         import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
          import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
           import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
         import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
          import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
       import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
      import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
      import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
       import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
       import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

@Controller
@Transactional
public class AdminController {

   @Autowired
   private OrderDAO orderDAO;

   @Autowired
   private ProductDAO productDAO;

   @Autowired
   private ProductFormValidator productFormValidator;



   @InitBinder
   public void myInitBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
      Object target = dataBinder.getTarget();
      if (target == null) {
         return;
      }
      System.out.println("Target=" + target);

      if (target.getClass() == ProductForm.class) {
         dataBinder.setValidator(productFormValidator);
      }
   }

   // GET: Show Login Page
   @RequestMapping(value = { "/admin/login" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String login(Model model) {

      return "login";
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = { "/admin/accountInfo" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String accountInfo(Model model) {

      UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
      System.out.println(userDetails.getPassword());
      System.out.println(userDetails.getUsername());
      System.out.println(userDetails.isEnabled());

      model.addAttribute("userDetails", userDetails);
      return "accountInfo";
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = { "/admin/orderList" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String orderList(Model model, //
         @RequestParam(value = "page", defaultValue = "1") String pageStr) {
      int page = 1;
      try {
         page = Integer.parseInt(pageStr);
      } catch (Exception e) {
      }
      final int MAX_RESULT = 5;
      final int MAX_NAVIGATION_PAGE = 10;

      PaginationResult<OrderInfo> paginationResult //
            = orderDAO.listOrderInfo(page, MAX_RESULT, MAX_NAVIGATION_PAGE);

      model.addAttribute("paginationResult", paginationResult);
      return "orderList";
   }

   // GET: Show product.
   @RequestMapping(value = { "/admin/product" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String product(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "code", defaultValue = "") String code) {
      ProductForm productForm = null;

      if (code != null && code.length() > 0) {
         Product product = productDAO.findProduct(code);
         if (product != null) {
            productForm = new ProductForm(product);
         }
      }
      if (productForm == null) {
         productForm = new ProductForm();
         productForm.setNewProduct(true);
      }
      model.addAttribute("productForm", productForm);
      return "product";
   }

   // POST: Save product
   @RequestMapping(value = { "/admin/product" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String productSave(Model model, //
         @ModelAttribute("productForm") @Validated ProductForm productForm, //
         BindingResult result, //
         final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

      if (result.hasErrors()) {
         return "product";
      }
      try {
         productDAO.save(productForm);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         Throwable rootCause = ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(e);
         String message = rootCause.getMessage();
         model.addAttribute("errorMessage", message);
         // Show product form.
         return "product";
      }

      return "redirect:/productList";
   }



   @RequestMapping(value = "product/{code}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
   public String delete(@PathVariable("code") String code) {
          productDAO.delete(code);
          return "redirect:/productList";
   } 






   @RequestMapping(value = { "/admin/order" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String orderView(Model model, @RequestParam("orderId") String orderId) {
      OrderInfo orderInfo = null;
      if (orderId != null) {
         orderInfo = this.orderDAO.getOrderInfo(orderId);
      }
      if (orderInfo == null) {
         return "redirect:/admin/orderList";
      }
      List<OrderDetailInfo> details = this.orderDAO.listOrderDetailInfos(orderId);
      orderInfo.setDetails(details);

      model.addAttribute("orderInfo", orderInfo);

      return "order";
   }


}
```

И класс ProductDAO:

```
package com.webapp.agroxapp.dao;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.NoResultException;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import com.webapp.agroxapp.entity.Product;
import com.webapp.agroxapp.form.ProductForm;
import com.webapp.agroxapp.model.ProductInfo;
import com.webapp.agroxapp.pagination.PaginationResult;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Transactional
@Repository
public class ProductDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Product findProduct(String code) {
        try {
            String sql = "Select e from " + Product.class.getName() + " e Where e.code =:code ";

            Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            Query<Product> query = session.createQuery(sql, Product.class);
            query.setParameter("code", code);
            return (Product) query.getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public ProductInfo findProductInfo(String code) {
        Product product = this.findProduct(code);
        if (product == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return new ProductInfo(product.getCode(), product.getName(), product.getPrice());
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void save(ProductForm productForm) {

        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        String code = productForm.getCode();

        Product product = null;

        boolean isNew = false;
        if (code != null) {
            product = this.findProduct(code);
        }
        if (product == null) {
            isNew = true;
            product = new Product();
            product.setCreateDate(new Date());
        }
        product.setCode(code);
        product.setName(productForm.getName());
        product.setPrice(productForm.getPrice());

        if (productForm.getFileData() != null) {
            byte[] image = null;
            try {
                image = productForm.getFileData().getBytes();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            if (image != null && image.length > 0) {
                product.setImage(image);
            }
        }
        if (isNew) {
            session.persist(product);
        }
        // If error in DB, Exceptions will be thrown out immediately
        session.flush();
    }





    public PaginationResult<ProductInfo> queryProducts(int page, int maxResult, int maxNavigationPage,
            String likeName) {
        String sql = "Select new " + ProductInfo.class.getName() //
                + "(p.code, p.name, p.price) " + " from "//
                + Product.class.getName() + " p ";
        if (likeName != null && likeName.length() > 0) {
            sql += " Where lower(p.name) like :likeName ";
        }
        sql += " order by p.createDate desc ";
        // 
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query<ProductInfo> query = session.createQuery(sql, ProductInfo.class);

        if (likeName != null && likeName.length() > 0) {
            query.setParameter("likeName", "%" + likeName.toLowerCase() + "%");
        }
        return new PaginationResult<ProductInfo>(query, page, maxResult, maxNavigationPage);
    }

    public PaginationResult<ProductInfo> queryProducts(int page, int maxResult, int maxNavigationPage) {
        return queryProducts(page, maxResult, maxNavigationPage, null);
    }

    public void delete(String code) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query deleteQuery = session.createQuery("DELETE FROM Product p WHERE p.code = :code");
        deleteQuery.setParameter("code", code);
        deleteQuery.executeUpdate();

    }


}
```

Как видно я прописал метод DELETE в AdminController:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "product/{code}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
   public String delete(@PathVariable("code") String code) {
          productDAO.delete(code);
          return "redirect:/productList";
   }
```

И в классе ProductDAO:

```
    public void delete(String code) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query deleteQuery = session.createQuery("DELETE FROM Product p WHERE p.code = :code");
        deleteQuery.setParameter("code", code);
        deleteQuery.executeUpdate();

    }
```

При попытке нажать на DELETE появляется ошибка

Whitelabel Error Page - This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Dec 03 22:00:10 GMT 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Так-же страница Thymeleaf:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
   xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Product List</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/styles.css}">
   </head>
   <body>
      <th:block th:include="/_header"></th:block>
      <th:block th:include="/_menu"></th:block>

      <div class="page-title">Product List</div>

      <div class="product-preview-container" th:each="prodInfo : ${paginationProducts.list}">
         <ul>
            <li><img class="product-image"
               th:src="@{|/productImage?code=${prodInfo.code}|}" /></li>
            <li>Code: <span th:utext="${prodInfo.code}"></span></li>
            <li>Name: <span th:utext="${prodInfo.name}"></span></li>
            <li>Price: <span th:utext="${#numbers.formatDecimal(prodInfo.price,3,2,'COMMA')}"></span></li>
            <li>
               <a th:href="@{|/buyProduct?code=${prodInfo.code}|}">Buy Now</a>
            </li>
            <!-- For Manager edit Product -->
            <th:block sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ROLE_MANAGER')">
               <li>
                 <a style="color:green;"
                    th:href="@{|/admin/product?code=${prodInfo.code}|}">Edit Product</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                                <a style="color:red;"
                    th:href="|@{admin/delete/${prodInfo.code}}|">Delete Product</a>

               </li>
               </li>
            </th:block>
         </ul>
      </div>

      <br/>
      <div class="page-navigator" th:if="${paginationProducts.totalPages > 1}">
         <th:block th:each="page : ${paginationProducts.navigationPages}">

            <a th:href="@{|/productList?page=${page}|}" th:if="${page != -1}"
               class="nav-item" th:utext="${page}"></a>

            <span class="nav-item" th:if="${page == -1}"> ... </span>

         </th:block>
      </div>

      <th:block th:include="/_footer"></th:block>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Так ты вызываешь admin/delete, когда у тебя нет для него ссылки
Исправь медот DELETE на :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "admin/delete/{code}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
   public String delete(@PathVariable("code") String code) {
          productDAO.delete(code);
          return "redirect:/productList";
   }
```